# Add Account (POST) Endpoint No Longer Working in new Yodlee API

Tags: yodlee

**OVERVIEW**

I am not sure what happened, as I have not touched my code that interacts with the Add Account endpoint in Yodlee (`POST /{cobrandName}/v1/providers/{providerId}`), but it has become broken (it was working as of Thursday). I am now getting this reply:

```
{ errorCode: 'Y400',
errorMessage: 'Null argument specified',
referenceCode: 'RB_134ae91e-4c80-4ad5-aac5-243ca428421d' }
```

**DETAILS**

I have the appropriate route params inserted into this `POST /{cobrandName}/v1/providers/{providerId}` and am passing a stringified JSON object as the request body (per the documentation) that looks like this:

```
{
    "provider": [{
        "id": 492,
        "name": "Fidelity Investments",
        "loginUrl": "https://login.fidelity.com/ftgw/Fas/Fidelity/RtlCust/Login/Init?AuthRedU",
        "baseUrl": "http://www.fidelity.com/",
        "favicon": "https://moneycenter.ydlstatic.com/fastlink/appscenter/siteImage.fastlink.do?access_type=APPS_CENTER_PRODUCTION&siteId=492&imageType=FAVICON",
        "logo": "https://moneycenter.ydlstatic.com/fastlink/appscenter/siteImage.fastlink.do?access_type=APPS_CENTER_PRODUCTION&siteId=492&imageType=LOGO",
        "status": "Supported",
        "mfaType": "Multiple levels of strong authentication.",
        "oAuthSite": false,
        "lastModified": "2016-03-31T10:39:36Z",
        "forgetPasswordUrl": "http://personal.fidelity.com/accounts/services/content/pinchange.shtml.tvsr",
        "containerNames": ["tax", "investment"],
        "loginForm": {
            "id": 172,
            "forgetPasswordURL": "http://personal.fidelity.com/accounts/services/content/pinchange.shtml.tvsr",
            "formType": "login",
            "row": [{
                "id": 4140,
                "label": "Username",
                "form": "0001",
                "fieldRowChoice": "0001",
                "field": [{
                    "id": 358,
                    "name": "LOGIN",
                    "maxLength": 15,
                    "type": "text",
                    "value": "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",
                    "isOptional": false,
                    "valueEditable": true
                }]
            }, {
                "id": 4139,
                "label": "Password",
                "form": "0001",
                "fieldRowChoice": "0002",
                "field": [{
                    "id": 357,
                    "name": "PASSWORD",
                    "maxLength": 20,
                    "type": "password",
                    "value": "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",
                    "isOptional": false,
                    "valueEditable": true
                }]
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

The form values are encrypted via PKI as per the documentation, using the key provided by the appropriate API endpoint, and I have both a cobrand session token and a yodlee user session token in the authentication headers (`'Authorization': 'cobSession={appToken}, userSession={token}'`). I was previously receiving back the expected 'refresh info' response using the same exact structure and process. I'm trying to understand what the 'null argument' referenced in the error is.

Comment: Is it still not working for you? Are you getting this every time or intermittently?

Comment: I used to not get this message at all with the same code flow on my end, but it started happening all of a sudden with every account/provider we try to add.

Comment: It seems like there was some issue during that specific time, it has been further analysed. Please get in touch with the Yodlee Support team to keep you updated with more details.